# Does SO upvote answers when you apply to jobs?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, upvotes

I have a feeling my answers get upvoted when I apply to jobs presented to me by Stack Overflow.  I imagine SO is incentivized to up-vote my answers so my profile looks more appealing to potential employers, which increases the probability of me getting hired - (I assume SO is compensated for placing candidates). Is there any truth to my wild accusations or should I put on a tinfoil hat?

Comment: I'm pretty sure every vote is tied to an account, so there's no concept of Stack Overflow the site upvoting your answers. This is a tinfoil hat situation <:-)

Comment: Here's a more plausible theory: when you apply to jobs, it increases your visibility, and some of those folks who see your application look at and upvote some of your answers.

Comment: SO charges a prohibitive amount of money for posting a job ad (enough so that we no longer use SO jobs to find candidates, it was way too expensive and didn't bring particularly good candidates, so we found that using a traditional recruiter was both more effective and cheaper), so I don't think they also charge extra if someone is hired through them.

Answer (score 9):

Applying for jobs has no bearing on your voting history.

Answer (score 3):

If the effect that you *think* you have observed is real (and it would be difficult to measure!), I expect it is due to upvotes from people in the employer organization viewing your answers while "scoping" you out; i.e. an organic effect.  (It could also be your friends trying to help you out ...)

It is hard to see how it would significantly benefit SO to record bogus votes in this scenario.  Certainly not to the extent that it would outweigh the possible downsides.  Like the credibility hit they would take if they were found to be doing this.

Comment: Adding your SO account to your Dev Story is optional and I'd say only a third of users do so. Even if this was the case, the effect would be statistically insignificant.